# Convert YYMMDD to YYYYMMDD and sort them

Tags: c++, sorting, date, integer, ofstream

```
#include <iostream>     // std::cout
#include <cstdlib>
#include <climits>
#include <algorithm>
#include <cmath>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

struct student{
    int ID;           // ID
    string firstname; // first name
    string lastname;  // last name
    int date;         // YYMMDD

    static bool sort_date(student a, student b){
        if(a.date < 150000){
            a.date += 20000000;
        }
        else{
            a.date += 19000000;
        }
        if(b.date < 150000){
            b.date += 20000000;
        }
        else{
            b.date += 19000000;
        }
        return data1 < data2;
    }

};

int main(){

    student students[5];

    students[0].date = 000101;
    students[1].date = 951230;
    students[2].date = 570509;
    students[3].date = 120915;
    students[4].date = 020324;

    stable_sort(students, students + 5, student::sort_date);

    ofstream file;
    file.open("sort_date.txt");
    for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
        file << students[i].date << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

This is my program and I have dates in format YYMMDD and I want to convert them in YYYYMMDD and sort them, but there is a problem in my algorithm which I can't find.

For some reason the sorted output in file looks like this:

```
570509
951230
65
8404
120915
```

I want my program, first, to take the dates:

```
students[0].date = 000101;
students[1].date = 951230;
students[2].date = 570509;
students[3].date = 120915;
students[4].date = 020324;
```

Then convert them to YYYYMMDD and sort them and output them in YYYYMMDD format. But the output is somehow wrong and convert 101 into 65 for some reason as well.

The correct output should be:

```
19570509
19951230
20000101
20020324
20120915
```

Comment: If you re-read the answers to your previous question, you will see that `000101` is an octal number. This is the same as `65` in decimal. This seems to be one of the issues with your code.

Comment: @juanchopanza But when you convert 000101 to YYYYMMDD, it becomes 20000101, which is still octal number?

Comment: But you don't convert it like that. You convert it to `20000065`. And you don't change the data in the array anyway, so you will be printing out the dates in the old format.

Comment: Hmm.. that's my problem. I don't know to fix it. Is there any way I can specify in the program that I'm using Decimals numbers?

Comment: @user2943407: Yes. _Stop writing leading zeros in literals_. If you want to align stuff, use spaces. Besides, this is kind of a strange way to build a `YYYYMMDD` representation. Typically we use strings for human-readable stuff.

Comment: Anything starting with `0` followed by digits will be treated as octal. You may be better off using strings, or writing a date class with separate fields for year, month and day.

Comment: @juanchopanza The problem is I can't use a class in this case. It's specified in the task what are we able to use. Other than using string, can I use std::dec to specify the format in decimal numbers?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I know everyone uses a string, and so would I, but the task specifies that I should use an integer :(

Comment: @user2943407: Who set this task?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit The professor of the class.

Comment: @user2943407: I'm sorry to hear that.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit So, is there any way I can fix this or not? :/

Comment: @user2943407 Don't forget to do the modifications first, and then sort afterward, without touching the dates. See my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The integer literal `000101` is interpreted as an octal representation of the decimal `65`, because of the leader zero.

A literal is a number written out in your source code. This does not include characters in a file, or characters inputted by a user into an I/O stream.

**Any integer literal beginning `0` is an octal integer literal.**

To stick to decimal literals, *do not use leading zeroes*.

```
students[0].date =    101;
students[1].date = 951230;
students[2].date = 570509;
students[3].date = 120915;
students[4].date =  20324;
```

As discussed above, this is kind of a strange way to do human-readable dates (typically you'd use a string for this, and leave the integer storage to some internal representation such as a UNIX timestamp).

Comment: How can I avoid using leading zeroes, if the year inputted by the user is 2000-2009 (starting with 0)?

Comment: @user2943407: It doesn't matter what the user input. The user input is not a literal. Literals are numbers that you write in your source code. I/O streams don't have this rule; that is: `stringstream ss("0101"); int x; ss >> x; cout << x;` results in `101`.

Comment: I understand. And if I were to use a string, could you give me an example how would it work? Thanks in advance.

Comment: @user2943407: At this point I will leave that as an exercise for you.

Comment: Alright, I'll see what I can do! I'll first of all, talk to the professor and ask if it's okay to use strings, or maybe he has a workaround of this problem. Thanks for your help nonetheless.

Comment: @user2943407: Good luck! If nothing else, I'm sure he'll be impressed by your question.

Answer (score 1):

You can't modify the sorted values while sorting. It's evil. The sort algorithm may launch "format C:" instead of actually sorting.

Beside, values to sort are passed by value to the callback, so your modification are lost.

1. Process your list of date for adjustments
2. Sort with a non modifying callback

(also, initialize your dates without the octal prefix, as in the @Lightness Races in Orbit answer)

Comment: He's not modifying them. Because, as you say, he takes by value. It looks deliberate to me — the pseudo-lexical conversion he's performing is only for ordering purposes. That being said, and I hadn't spotted this before, he _will_ need new logic to re-apply that conversion for output.

Comment: He wants a "correct output" with "19570509", so he believes that modifications will stay. Anyway, I really don't like the idea of altering values WHILE sorting. Do it a certain way, and it's UB, IMHO.

Comment: Of course! The standard mandates that `Compare` does not modify its arguments. Modifying during sorting is bad and wrong.